# how to build a vc++ file in commandline

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

How to build a Project developed in VC++  in command line i am not visual studio(2003or 2005 or 2008)

Comment: I can't really understand your question, can you provide more detail? What command are you trying to use and what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not have understood your question fully, but using the /build param to devenv.exe will enable you to build a solution from the command line.